# how to redirect to login view in admin panel in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have Login page which has very simple contents without sidebar, top navigation, and the another page the home view which has main contents, sidebar, top navigation but wants to load login view without sidebar, top navigation.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router' , 'ngMessages']);
app.config(function($stateProvider , $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
            .state('index',{
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/index.html'
            })

            .state("helper",{
                url:"/helper",
                templateUrl : "views/helper.html",
                controller: 'helperController',
            })

             .state('login',{
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            })

    //By Default Load the template
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

app.controller('helperController',function($scope , $http){
    $scope.addHelper = function(){
        var data = [{
            first_name : $scope.first_name,
            last_name : $scope.last_name,
            email : $scope.email,
            phone : $scope.phone,
            state : $scope.state,
            city : $scope.city,
            zip_code : $scope.zip_code,
            address : $scope.address,
            password : $scope.password,
        }];
        console.log(data);
    }
});

app.controller('loginController', ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$state", function ($scope, $rootScope, $state) {       
  $state.go('login');
}]);
```

login page:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Gentallela Alela! | </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styling plus plugins -->
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/icheck/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background:#F7F7F7;">

  <div class="">
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="login" class="animate form">
        <section class="login_content">
          <form>
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" />
          </div>
          <div>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
          </div>
          <div>
              <a class="btn btn-default submit" href="index.html">Log in</a>
              <a class="reset_pass" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="separator">

              <p class="change_link">New to site?
                <a href="#toregister" class="to_register"> Create Account </a>
            </p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <h1><i class="fa fa-paw" style="font-size: 26px;"></i> Gentelella Alela!</h1>

                <p>©2015 All Rights Reserved. Gentelella Alela! is a Bootstrap 3 template. Privacy and Terms</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- form -->
</section>
<!-- content -->
</div>
<div id="register" class="animate form">
    <section class="login_content">
      <form>
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
      </div>
      <div>
          <a class="btn btn-default submit" href="index.html">Submit</a>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="separator">

          <p class="change_link">Already a member ?
            <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Log in </a>
        </p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <h1><i class="fa fa-paw" style="font-size: 26px;"></i> Gentelella Alela!</h1>

            <p>©2015 All Rights Reserved. Gentelella Alela! is a Bootstrap 3 template. Privacy and Terms</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- form -->
</section>
<!-- content -->
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

master layout:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Gentallela Alela! | </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styling plus plugins -->
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" />
  <link href="css/icheck/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/floatexamples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>


<body class="nav-md"  ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view="login"></div>
  <div class="container body">


    <div class="main_container">

      <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
        <div class="left_col scroll-view">

          <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
            <a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>Gentellela Alela!</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- menu prile quick info -->
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile_pic">
              <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
          </div>
          <div class="profile_info">
              <span>Welcome,</span>
              <h2>John Doe</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /menu prile quick info -->

      <br />

      <!-- sidebar menu -->
      <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">

        <div class="menu_section">
          <h3>General</h3>
          <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard </a>
            </li>
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Helper <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: none">
                <li><a href="#/helper">Add New Helpers</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="form_advanced.html">List Helpers</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>



    </ul>
</div>


</div>
<!-- /sidebar menu -->

<!-- /menu footer buttons -->
<div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lock">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- /menu footer buttons -->
</div>
</div>

    <!-- top navigation -->
    <div class="top_nav">

    <div class="nav_menu">
      <nav class="" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav toggle">
          <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="">John Doe
              <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
              <li><a href="javascript:;">  Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                  <span class="badge bg-red pull-right">50%</span>
                  <span>Settings</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle info-number" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
      <span class="badge bg-green">6</span>
  </a>
  <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">
      <li>
        <a>
          <span class="image">
            <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" />
        </span>
        <span>
            <span>John Smith</span>
            <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
        </span>
        <span class="message">
            Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
      <span class="image">
        <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>John Smith</span>
        <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
    </span>
    <span class="message">
        Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
    </span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
      <span class="image">
        <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>John Smith</span>
        <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
    </span>
    <span class="message">
        Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
    </span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
      <span class="image">
        <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>John Smith</span>
        <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
    </span>
    <span class="message">
        Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
    </span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="inbox.html">
        <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>

</div>
    <!-- /top navigation -->


    <!-- page content -->
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
    <!-- /page content -->

<!-- footer content -->
    <footer>
    <div class="pull-right">
      Gentelella - Bootstrap Admin Template by <a href="https://colorlib.com">Colorlib</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</footer>
<!-- /footer content -->
</div>
</div>

<div id="custom_notifications" class="custom-notifications dsp_none">
    <ul class="list-unstyled notifications clearfix" data-tabbed_notifications="notif-group">
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="notif-group" class="tabbed_notifications"></div>
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- gauge js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gauge/gauge.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gauge/gauge_demo.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap progress js -->
<script src="js/progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
<!-- icheck -->
<script src="js/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- chart js -->
<script src="js/chartjs/chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

<!-- flot js -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/curvedLines.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // [17, 74, 6, 39, 20, 85, 7]
      //[82, 23, 66, 9, 99, 6, 2]
      var data1 = [
      [gd(2012, 1, 1), 17],
      [gd(2012, 1, 2), 74],
      [gd(2012, 1, 3), 6],
      [gd(2012, 1, 4), 39],
      [gd(2012, 1, 5), 20],
      [gd(2012, 1, 6), 85],
      [gd(2012, 1, 7), 7]
      ];

      var data2 = [
      [gd(2012, 1, 1), 82],
      [gd(2012, 1, 2), 23],
      [gd(2012, 1, 3), 66],
      [gd(2012, 1, 4), 9],
      [gd(2012, 1, 5), 119],
      [gd(2012, 1, 6), 6],
      [gd(2012, 1, 7), 9]
      ];
      $("#canvas_dahs").length && $.plot($("#canvas_dahs"), [
        data1, data2
        ], {
            series: {
              lines: {
                show: false,
                fill: true
            },
            splines: {
                show: true,
                tension: 0.4,
                lineWidth: 1,
                fill: 0.4
            },
            points: {
                radius: 0,
                show: true
            },
            shadowSize: 2
        },
        grid: {
          verticalLines: true,
          hoverable: true,
          clickable: true,
          tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
          borderWidth: 1,
          color: '#fff'
      },
      colors: ["rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.38)", "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.38)"],
      xaxis: {
          tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
          mode: "time",
          tickSize: [1, "day"],
          //tickLength: 10,
          axisLabel: "Date",
          axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
          axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
          axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
          axisLabelPadding: 10
            //mode: "time", timeformat: "%m/%d/%y", minTickSize: [1, "day"]
        },
        yaxis: {
          ticks: 8,
          tickColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.06)",
      },
      tooltip: false
  });

      function gd(year, month, day) {
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime();
    }
});
</script>

<!-- worldmap -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/maps/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/maps/gdp-data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/maps/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/maps/jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js"></script>
<!-- pace -->
<script src="js/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        series: {
          regions: [{
            values: gdpData,
            scale: ['#E6F2F0', '#149B7E'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
        }]
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code) {
      el.html(el.html() + ' (GDP - ' + gdpData[code] + ')');
  }
});
  });
</script>
<!-- skycons -->
<script src="js/skycons/skycons.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var icons = new Skycons({
        "color": "#73879C"
    }),
    list = [
    "clear-day", "clear-night", "partly-cloudy-day",
    "partly-cloudy-night", "cloudy", "rain", "sleet", "snow", "wind",
    "fog"
    ],
    i;

    for (i = list.length; i--;)
      icons.set(list[i], list[i]);

  icons.play();
</script>

<!-- Doughnut Chart -->
<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
      var options = {
        legend: false,
        responsive: false
    };

    new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1"), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)",
        data: {
          labels: [
          "Symbian",
          "Blackberry",
          "Other",
          "Android",
          "IOS"
          ],
          datasets: [{
            data: [15, 20, 30, 10, 30],
            backgroundColor: [
            "#BDC3C7",
            "#9B59B6",
            "#E74C3C",
            "#26B99A",
            "#3498DB"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#CFD4D8",
            "#B370CF",
            "#E95E4F",
            "#36CAAB",
            "#49A9EA"
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: options
});
});
</script>
<!-- /Doughnut Chart -->

<!-- datepicker -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var cb = function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        //alert("Callback has fired: [" + start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ", label = " + label + "]");
    }

    var optionSet1 = {
        startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
        endDate: moment(),
        minDate: '01/01/2012',
        maxDate: '12/31/2015',
        dateLimit: {
          days: 60
      },
      showDropdowns: true,
      showWeekNumbers: true,
      timePicker: false,
      timePickerIncrement: 1,
      timePicker12Hour: true,
      ranges: {
          'Today': [moment(), moment()],
          'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
          'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
          'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
          'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
          'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      },
      opens: 'left',
      buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
      applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
      cancelClass: 'btn-small',
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
      separator: ' to ',
      locale: {
          applyLabel: 'Submit',
          cancelLabel: 'Clear',
          fromLabel: 'From',
          toLabel: 'To',
          customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
          daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
          monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
          firstDay: 1
      }
  };
  $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);
  $('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("show event fired");
});
  $('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("hide event fired");
});
  $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
});
  $('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("cancel event fired");
});
  $('#options1').click(function() {
    $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setOptions(optionSet1, cb);
});
  $('#options2').click(function() {
    $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').setOptions(optionSet2, cb);
});
  $('#destroy').click(function() {
    $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').remove();
});
});
</script>
<script>
    NProgress.done();
</script>
<!-- /datepicker -->
<!-- /footer content -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@saddam, yes, you can do this with a flag.

Create two varous Content in the Header.html file with an ng-if="toggleHeader".

1. one content is used to display the before login i.e., when toggleHeader is FALSE.
2. Another content will be loaded when login is success. we have to set the toggleHeader to 'TRUE'

Steps: 
1.open login screen.
2. Provide Credentials for Login and once the BackEnd Call gets success set a flag value i.e., $scope.toggleHeader = true; Send these values via $stateParams
3. That's it, your task will be completed.

Please reply for any queries here, just in case.